# Setear valor de una propiedad de solo lectura por medio de un campo

Tags: c#

Tengo una respuesta de una API externa que entre algunas propiedades me devuelve un `string` llamado `"status"`. Este `status`, puede devolverme `"ERROR"`, en caso de que eso suceda, yo quiero tener una clase que tenga una propiedad de solo lectura llamada `IsSuccess` (bool) que se setee automáticamente al instanciarse, determinando si es verdadera o falsa dependiendo si la respuesta viene con "status: "ERROR"" esta sea falsa, y en caso contrario sea verdadera.

¿Como podría realizarlo en la misma declaración de la clase, usando propiedades y campos?
Gracias.

Edito con una forma que estaba tratando de realizar, pero no funciona porque el momento en el que el `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` crea esta clase en base al parámetro, `Status` es `null`.

```
public class TestResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; }

    [JsonProperty("answer")]
    public ResponseError Error { get; set; }

    public TestResponse()
    {
        if (Status == "ERROR")
            IsSuccess = false;
        else
            IsSuccess = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué te impide inicializar esa propiedad en el constructor y no crearle un setter? No entiendo cual es el problema. Si pudieras agregar más contexto y algo de código.

Comment: Porque estoy usando JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MiClase> y si en el constructor hago algo como if (Status == "ERROR") IsSucess = false, este me devuelve true igual porque Status esta nulo. Igual ahi puse lo que trate de hacer en el constructor.

Comment: ¿Qué tal una propiedad así: `public bool IsSuccess => this.Status != "ERROR";`?

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso funciono.

Comment: Si no estoy errado, creo que debes agregarle el atributo `Serializable` a la clase y `JsonIgnore` a la propiedad que no guarda un valor (`IsSuccess`). Por cierto, otra opción podría ser que la propiedad sea `{ get; init; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [Expression-bodied members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties) introducida en `C# 6` para crear propiedades de solo lectura con la sintaxis de lambda.

Necesitas una propiedad de solo lectura que sea `false`, solo cuando `Status` es igual a `"ERROR"`, y `true` en cualquier otro caso. Por tanto, una posible implementación sería:

```
public bool IsSuccess => this.Status != "ERROR";
```

Nota que esto es equivalente en las viejas versiones de C# a implementar el `get`:

```
public bool IsSuccess
{
    get
    {
       return this.Status != "ERROR";
    }
}
```